# ios midi voice like(0x90,30,127)

Tags: ios, midi, audio, piano

**I had a piano ios applications, I can use CoreMidi normally receive external MIDI controller information, but no voice. So I want to use MIDI like (0x90,30,127) bytes to make a sound, can someone answer my question? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Not likely, unless you drastically improve the question. Please read this advice on [ask] and Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article. The more effort you put into asking your question, the more likely you are to get answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean uses iOS device as MIDI Synthesizer (sound output from iOS device),

You needs `AUGraph` & `AudioUnit` (Look up in Xcode Help search for "Sampler Unit Presets (LoadPresetDemo)")

After you understand that some tips from me:

1. define your custom structure that contains `AUGraph` & `AudioUnit`.
2. pass your custom structure pointer as `refCon` in `MIDIInputPortCreate` or `srcConnRefCon` in `MIDIPortConnectSource` for call functions such as `MusicDeviceMIDIEvent` in your `MIDIReadProc` at that callback thread.

Comment: This is [not an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Stack Overflow has a question-and-answer format, not a discussion thread format. "Answer" means you're actually providing an answer to the question; it's not the same as "Reply" in a discussion forum. Once you have at least 50 rep, you can [post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) to seek clarification about something, but be sure to read the "When *shouldn't* I comment?" section. Please read the [About] page to get a better understanding of the site's format.

Comment: That's right! It can also make the SoundFonts by changing like (0xc0 30) .

Comment: I've used this project before, but can't seem to change timbre (0xC0 30)                                                                                 - (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender {
    
 UInt32 noteNum = 60;
 UInt32 noteCommand =  0xC0 | 0;
 
    MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(self.samplerUnit, noteCommand, noteNum, 0, 0);
    
}

Comment: I want to know whether certain need to sound files to make these sound, can need not？

Comment: thank you !It seems I want to understand the project in-depth